# PDFBox 2.0.3: PDDocument Scratch File Already Closed

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm generating a PDDocument in Java with code like this...

```
HashMap<Integer, PDPageContentStream> mPageContentStreamMap = new HashMap<>();
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
for (int i = 1; i <= mNumPages; i++) {
        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
        page.setRotation(90);
        PDPageContentStream pageContentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
        contentStreamMap.put(i, pageContentStream);
        doc.addPage(page);
    }
}
```

Then later save and close the document like this...

```
for (int i : mPageContentStreamMap.keySet()) {
    mPageContentStreamMap.get(i).close();
}

doc.save("test-filename");
doc.close();
```

This works fine on the first run; however when I run my program multiple times I get the following error

```
java.io.IOException: Scratch file already closed
at org.apache.pdfbox.io.ScratchFile.checkClosed(ScratchFile.java:390)
at org.apache.pdfbox.io.ScratchFileBuffer.<init>(ScratchFileBuffer.java:78)
at org.apache.pdfbox.io.ScratchFile.createBuffer(ScratchFile.java:403)
at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.createOutputStream(COSStream.java:208)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream.createOutputStream(PDStream.java:224)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.<init>(PDPageContentStream.java:259)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.<init>(PDPageContentStream.java:121)
```

If I re-run my program without the "doc.close();" line, this error goes away, but the output of the PDF is duplicated (i.e. a new PDF is generated, but with the content from the last PDF and the content from the current PDF).

Is there a way to close the stream and create multiple PDFs without running into the scratch file error?

Comment: "when I run my program multiple times" means what? Which part is repeated? I'm asking because the PageContentStream you created is "bound" to the document.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I run the program (main generation method with code above) in a while loop that continues to generate PDF's until a user enters an invalid input. If I run the program just once (no while loop), and restart the program it works fine, but I need it in a loop.

Comment: To further clarify, I create a 'generator' object once and continuously call the 'generate' method on that object in the loop.

Comment: Let me ask this differently - when is the contentstreammap initialized? From what I see, `mPageContentStreamMap.get(i)` will get the content streams of old documents if you don't empty it or create it.

Comment: mPageContentStreamMap is initialized to a new HashMap right before I do PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();

Comment: Can you create a minimal self-working program that brings the error? Either the bug is on your side but isn't shown (or isn't obvious) in the code snippets, or the bug is in PDFBox and then we need to fix it. Btw your map is once named `mPageContentStreamMap` and once `contentStreamMap`.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Turns out to be a problem with my code and not PDFBox, sorry for the scare. I had created a singleton object for my drawing logic meaning after the first run, the same objects were reused when they shouldn't've been.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had created a singleton object for my drawing logic meaning after the first run, the same objects were reused when they shouldn't've been, because the input (what was being drawn) had changed.